# str_replace emoticons Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to replace text with emoticons. The problem is that I don't know how to replace a lot of them. At this time I have this code which is working:

```
<p>
    {!! str_replace(':D', '<img src="/emoticons/grin.png" alt="">', $post->content) !!}
</p>
```

So when I write ":D", the emoticon  is working fine, but I don't know how to add more emoticons.

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace it by array as:

```
$emotions = array(":D", ":)", ":(");
$images   = array("<img src=\"/emoticons/grin.png\" alt=\"\">", "<img src=\"/emoticons/img2.png\" alt=\"\">", "<img src=\"/emoticons/img3.png\" alt=\"\">");
//Then replace
<p>{!! str_replace($emotions, $images, $post->content) !!}</p>
```

Note that: $emotions and $images must be pair in order.
You can learn about str_replace at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php